# jquery cycle on an ajax loaded page with hash

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am using ajax to load content from other html documents into a div #content - the url then becomes mydomain/index.html#user1. Each "user" html document has a jquery cycle slideshow. If I look at the user page independently (not loaded via ajax) the slideshow works fine. If I look at the user page loaded via ajax on the index page, the slideshow does not work.

I call jquery and cycle from index here is what i have at the top:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// slideshow
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    prev:   '#prev', 
    next:   '#next', 
    timeout: 0 
});
// Check for hash value in URL  
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('.thumbgroup div a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

// project-links
$('.thumbgroup div a').click(function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#header').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());

        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I've tried calling cycle from the loaded page and it still does not work. I would be very grateful if anyone had any ideas for this newbie! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure your javascript that use for slideshow are being loaded or not.If not, try do this before the loading the content.

```
  var script=document.createElement('script');
  script.type='text/javascript';
  path = {locate your js files}
  script.src= path+'jquery.js'; 
  $("body").append(script);
```